# Armazenar valores representantes do 'sexo' de um usuário em bancos de dados

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelagem

Tenho algumas duvidas quanto a representação de alguns campos em banco de dados. Como devo armazenar campos como "sexo" em tabelas no banco de dados? Na forma literal "masculino" e "feminino" ou através de números que representam cada sexo como "1" e "2", respectivamente? Esta dúvida se estende a outros campos, por exemplo, há uma necessidade de armazenar a classificação de peso de um objeto em "muito leve", "leve", "médio", "pesado" e "muito pesado". Eu deveria armazenar um numero representante de cada categoria?

Comment: Depende de como vc usar na aplicação. Eu sempre crio uma tabela do tipo Sexo:[id, nome]. Assim tenho ele representado tanto com número como string.

Comment: @Earendul este id seria dado por mim ou este é um id tipo INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT usado para ser chave primaria

Comment: @Earendul Eu acho que esse seu comentário vale uma resposta. :) Até porque, armazenar diretamente na forma literal gera dificuldades com localização (apresentação em diferentes idiomas).

Comment: @RicardoHenrique Como provavelmente são apenas 2 registros ('M' e 'F') você mesmo pode definir o número, e pode ser chave primaria já que nunca vai haver dois números iguais e poderá relacionar com outras tabelas

Comment: Criar uma tabela para deixar eternamente com 2 registros apenas não seria um tanto quanto inutil ? Não é mais prático, fácil, funcional estabelecer isso via código ? Constante ou Enum ???

Comment: Você vai gastar uma tabela em seu SGDB, terá que fazer a query (selects e os joins), processar a query e o resultado apenas para comprovar algo que você já sabe ? Afinal foi você mesmo que populou a tabela e ela não é alterada...PHP não possui a estrutura Enum, mas podemos facilmente implementa-la desta forma: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/254514/php-and-enumerations

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depende de cada caso.

O que eu nunca recomendo, mas pode haver exceções, é usar a descrição completa. Não estará errado usar a descrição se tiver um bom motivo para isso. Se não usar a descrição e exista uma que deve ser usada em algumas situações você terá que tratar isso de alguma forma.

Em muitos casos um código basta. Até por força externa, legislação por exemplo, pode ser que o correto seja colocar 1 ou 2 e é só isto que importa. Em outro deve colocar M ou F e não precisa de nenhuma descrição além desta. Então deve usar apenas isto. Ou seja, a coluna já é auto descritiva desta forma.

Mas pode ser que você precise de uma descrição extra. Aí tem três soluções:

1. Você deixa para uma *stored procedure* resolver isso ou para a aplicação tratar já que esta descrição não costuma mudar. Muitas pessoas irão criticar esta opção porque o banco de dados não está sendo usado de forma apropriada. Eu concordo com as críticas, mas faço a ressalva que pode haver motivo, especialmente para deixar para a aplicação tratar disto quando a descrição pode mudar dependendo do contexto de execução. Provavelmente não ocorrerá com sexo mas pode ocorrer com outros tipos.
2. Cria uma tabela auxiliar com as descrições e fazer um relacionamento, uma solução muito comum. Ela é bastante recomendada. Ao contrário do que muitos se esquecem, ainda é necessário outro ponto do banco de dados ou aplicação saber como manipular esta informação e adequadamente se o interesse é receber a descrição do dado. Evidentemente que neste caso um 1 ou 2 será um `ID` para a tabela referenciada. Este `ID` costuma ser um número mas não precisa ser, pode ser um caractere e usar o `M` ou `F`, parece uma boa [chave natural](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/277091/101).
3. Criar uma enumeração, se o sistema usado permite. Alguns criticam o seu uso porque o recurso pode ter limitações. Mas pode resolver bem na maioria dos casos. No fundo é uma forma padronizada do banco de dados de usar uma tabela auxiliar. Ainda terá que fazer algo na recuperação de dados para pegar a descrição.

Como eu disse, eu acho mais organizado e flexível destas formas, especialmente a número 2, assim é a forma normalizada. Mas se quiser facilitar a consulta, dar um pouco mais de performance, então jogar a descrição direto é a solução, assim você já recebe o que quer sem precisar usar artifícios na *query*.

Mas lembre-se que isso poderá trazer algumas dores de cabeça se tiver alguma razão para alterar estas descrições. Nada que não possa ser resolvido nos casos de dados bem simples como os descritos. Em dados mais complexos pode ser que você nunca poderá desambiguar se houver uma alteração. Não faça isto com nomes de cidades, por exemplo.

Só não vai usar booleano. Já vi isto quando só havia dois valores e está errado.

Tem uma [ISO sobre o uso de sexo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_5218).

Mais recentemente criaram um conceito de gênero com dados mais flexíveis em que a pessoa pode escolher mais livremente o que ele se considera. Até o momento não foi criado novos sexos e provavelmente não faz sentido ter novos porque é uma questão biológica. Se ele não é mais adequado então deve ser excluído para o gênero tomar lugar.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 1):

No caso de informação fixa, como é este o caso. Só existem 3 possibilidades:

- Masculino
- Feminino
- Indefinido (no caso do seu sistema permitir que a pessoa não defina o sexo).

Logo, esses dados são fixos e não precisam de uma tabela em seu banco de dados, isso seria um completo desperdício de recursos.

Crie uma classe com as constantes e pronto.

```
<?php
abstract class Sexo
{
    const Indefinido = 0;
    const Masculino = 1;
    const Feminino = 2;

   public getStringValue($value)
   {
       switch($value)
       {
           case self::Indefindo:
               return "Indefinido";
           case self::Masculino:
               return "Masculino";
           case self::Feminino:
               return "Feminino";
           default:
               return "Valor não é válido";
       }
   }
}
?>
```

Quando precisar utilizar basta fazer o seguinte:

```
<?php
    $meuSexo = Sexo::Masculino;
    //var_dump($meuSexo) => 1

    $string = Sexo.getStringValue($meuSexo);
    //var_dump($string) => Masculino
?>
```

Comment: Creio que atualmente existam muito mais do que apenas 3 possibilidades, vide o leque de opções do facebook.

Answer (score -2):

A fim de curiosidade:

No caso de peso de um objeto em "muito leve", "leve", "médio", "pesado" e "muito pesado". Podemos utilizar alguns métodos de estatística pra definir um intervalo.

Portanto se temos 50 produtos, com a seguinte listagem de peso:

1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 
7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 15, 16, 16, 16, 17, 
18, 18, 18, 18 ,18, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 
47, 47, 47, 49, 49, 50, 55, 58, 59, 90.

Temos o maior valor como 90 e o menor como 1, portanto nossa amplitude de amostragem é de AA = 89 (90 - 1).

Em seguida calculamos o i, que teoricamente seria a quantidade de agrupamentos que precisamos ter: i = 1 + 3.3 log 50 = 6,6 ~ 7 (arredondamento normal).

Portanto o ideal seria ter 7 classificações de peso, mas pra este exemplo iremos utilizar os 5 já classificados por você, portanto considere i = 5.

Precisamos agora calcular quais serão os intervalos
AA / i = 89/5 = 17,8 ~ 18 (sempre arredondado pra cima).

Muito Leve: 1 |- 19
Leve: 19 |- 37
Médio: 37 |- 55
Pesado: 55 |- 73
Muito Pesado: 73 |- 91

```
<?php
abstract class Peso
{
   public getStringValue($value)
   {
       if ($value < 19){
          return "Muito Leve";
       }elseif($value < 37){
          return "Leve";
       }elseif($value < 55){
          return "Médio";
       }elseif($value < 73){
          return "Pesado";
       }else{
          return "Muito Pesado";
       }
   }
}
?>
```